# How to create a shortcut for invoking Mosh from Google's Secure Shell extension?

Tags: google-chrome, ssh, google-chrome-extensions, mosh

This boils down to a question **how to invoke a certain page of the [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/iodihamcpbpeioajjeobimgagajmlibd) from the command line.** The SSH extension can be invoked by

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome_proxy.exe"  --profile-directory=Default \
  --app-id=iheocdlapopnjhneafdihoapcfncnbbf
```

which is the regular shortcut created by Chrome. But I couldn't figure out how to invoke Mosh that's bundled with it.

Inspecting the *Mosh* link in the extensions menu using Chrome's dev tools leads to [nassh_extension_popup.js](https://chromium.googlesource.com/apps/libapps/+/HEAD/nassh/js/nassh_extension_popup.js), and reading the code suggests that the desired URL is `chrome-extension://iheocdlapopnjhneafdihoapcfncnbbf/plugin/mosh/mosh_client.html?promptOnReload=yes&openas=#profile-id:mosh`. But Chrome doesn't accept the URL as an `--app-id` argument, and neither works passing it as (another) argument or experimenting with [other similar flags](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).